# How would you verify Android battery stats apps?

Tags: battery

This is more a question about diagnosing battery and battery hardware, than it is specifically about Android. If there is a better StackExchange site for this question to belong to, please tell me, I will repost there instead.

There are apps like [Battery Guru](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paget96.batteryguru) and [Kaspersky Battery Life](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kaspersky.batterysaver) which are very effective at taking battery sensor data and breaking it down for you, and explaining the health of the battery to you.

I want to know how do I verify the veracity of the information that Battery Guru is reporting myself. I understand that I could write an Android app that does what Battery Guru does. I am assuming that these apps take the information that standard Android APIs provide to the user and present it to them and do some math on that data provided by Android.

I am assuming these apps are basically just reading [BatteryManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager) and presenting it to the user meaningfully. Is there any other way besides writing my own app to verify that the information provided is accurate? Is there anything like a hardware device that can be used to test the battery directly (implying that I would be opening up the device)?

Comment: Get hardware info directly from kernel through `sys` interface: `/sys/class/power_supply/battery/`.